# Create custom currency programmatically in magento

Tags: currency

I want to add my own currency in magento like as **other currencies**,and also for the created **currency** I want to set rate.
how I can do this.
Is there any idea?

Comment: I would like to upvote this question because I think it's interesting. But you don't tell us what you have tried, what didn't work, or why you are unsure of an approach you came up with, and so it's a poor question. :(

Comment: I didn't tried anything yet...Wont be able to understand how I start to create my own currency. Which step I need to follow wont be able to understand.If you have any idea please share with me as I was searching from last 3 days.. but didn't get the appropriate solution yet.

Comment: Hi , I just tried http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5275815/how-do-i-create-a-custom-currency-type-in-magento-or-zend?answertab=oldest#tab-top this solution but still nothing happened please let me know what should I try..

Comment: Hm, the solution looks good to me, did you get any error?

Comment: No but I didn't get that currency which I added in en.xml file as suggested by above post which I used.